# Is their any JavaScript Annotation Library?

Tags: javascript, annotations

Is their any good JavaScript open source library which read annotations defined on JavaScript function and variables? Like we have in Java.

Comment: impossible as javascript is interpeted not compiled, java annoations add compile time metadata

Comment: If not annotation then is their any framework which parse comments, like YUIDoc and JSDoc library works. They parse comments to prepare JavaScript Documentation

Comment: never heard of them, why not just use them then ?

Comment: These libraries are actually used to generate JavaScript documentation using an-noted comments

Example: 
      
/**
   XYZ Method 

   @method xyz
*/
function xyz() { }

I am not sure how to use them for defining our own annotation, I was thinking if their is any such library which read comments and annotation so that we can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are now - although they require your javascript to be compiled.

This SO answer covers the same topic:  [JavaScript annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065949/javascript-annotations)

It has some interesting thoughts on how you might implement a variation of annotations yourself.

Notably, it references the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/), which uses annotations - although it manages to do it *because* it is compiled.

Also, [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (server side javascript) has an npm for [docblock style annotations](https://npmjs.org/package/annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Well in ES2016 you can use the same decorator pattern. I've created a module that let you easily wrap/inject your original code with your own.

https://github.com/cmartin81/decorator-wrap